# Doubt on prevention of CSRF

Tags: csrf, csrf-protection

I had one doubt about CSRF prevention. A lot of sites say that CSRF can be prevented by using 'tokens' which are randomly generated per session.

Now my doubt is,
suppose i have  a function like :

```
$.post("abcd.php",{'fbuid':userid,'code':'<?php echo  md5($_SESSION['randcode']); ?>'}
```

now this md5 hash would obviously be visible to any hacker through the source code.He could simply open this page, generate a token, and keep the page open, so that the session doesn't get destroyed, and useanother tab or anything else , to start hacking,

No ?

Or is my idea of tokens incorrect ?

Thanks for your help :D

Comment: probably you need to encrypt and pass the data

Comment: @kobe umm,yeah that could be done, but then i'd need a very strong encryption algorithm wouldn't I ? and since it would be possible to decrypt it unless its something like md5 , hence it won't be very secure - this is what i was thinking

Comment: Wow you need to read about CSRF because you don't have a clue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding what needs to be done. To protect against CSRF you need to create a token and save it for that session. Then you need to append all your submits and AJAX calls with that token.

For another person to send you to a page on your website they would need to have access to the request with in the **same session**. It is true that one could parse the HTML and look for the token. But when they try to request a http call on your website they will have a **new** session created. The new session will have a new token which will not match the token that was passed.

Next you will ask what if you can copy the cookies and the session id as a result. This is not something that is protected. I can simply sit anybody's computer and copy all their cookies and I will then be logged in as them.

Comment: Also it is true that you should destroy the token each time. But that only protects again replay attacks.

Comment: Some papers don't suggest to destroy it. We made it destroyed after each request to make the client happy. But really this will work. You just need to make sure one can't infer the secret token from the cookie id.

Comment: Good read http://shiflett.org/articles/cross-site-request-forgeries Uses php but same idea.

Comment: @Amir Raminfar : Thanks a LOT for this answer :D If i do something as simple as "View Source" for any code, does it create a new session :O ? Because anyone can just view my HTML source very easily.

Comment: @Anant yes if YOU view the source it does. But we are not protecting against you! We are protecting against an automated bot which will read the html page. That bot, will have a different session. Why would we want to protect YOU, when you are the person who is logged in.

Comment: @Amir Raminfar : Against BOTS i understand, but what if a user tries to use that for one sucessful malicious request ?
Thanks

Comment: @Anant, I guess you have to explain to me how someone would do that. If a malicious user was sitting at your computer then they can just do whatever. Give me a scanrio of where someone who is not sitting at your computer can do a malicious request.

Comment: @Amir Raminfar so its not possible for a malicious user to send POST requests to my server without being on my computer?

Comment: If you are sitting the computer then you can do anything. If a malicious user some how get your token then they need your session id too. Even then your token would be different than some one else's token because it is different session. So no there is no way. :)

Comment: @Amir Raminfar One last time : suppose the user opens up the page,right clicks andb views the source of the page.then he gets the token for the current session. He opens up another tab,and uses the token wit his own malicious script. This way,the session is intact, and the token has been stolen too! How can this be prevented ?
Thanks for being patient with me.im a web security newbie!  :)

Comment: @Anant, is the user sitting at the computer? If so then yes this possible. You can't protect this. If you leave your email open and I sit at your computer then that's user error. If you still the token from another computer then it won't work since its your own session. I think you are confused because you keep thinking about the someone sitting at your computer. This is not CSRF.

Answer (score 3):

As kapep points out, you are confusing the two seperate issues of input validation and cross-site form posting. You must validate your inputs anyway, so the case of your malicious attacker using his own session token is already handled if you have sound input validation. CSRF protection is not there to protect the data, it is simply to ensure that only forms from your own application can post data back to that application. the CSRF protection is simply stopping other people being able to post data directly into your app from forms they put up on their own site.

One specific point to be aware of is that the token is visible to any javascript running on your page, so as soon as you have a cross-site scripting (XSS) vulnerability, your CSRF protection is defeated.

See [Cross-site scripting](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29) and the [prevention cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: okay, i think i'm starting to get it. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

You should use a per request token.

1. Generate a token and store it in the session.
2. Pass the token to the client.
3. Execute actions.
4. Destroy the token.

The token is safer and cannot be used more than one time.

Comment: thanks for the reply. How do i destroy the token ? Is there any way of running a script by which i could destroy the token as soon as my webpage loses focus ?
My main concern is that, the token could easily be copied,and used again, with the session not being destroyed with any mechanism as described above.

Comment: Well you can destroy the token when it is used. For instance when you receive a POST with the token you delete it from the session so that it couldn't be used again.

Comment: What if the person, just *sees* the token code from my $.post() request,and uses it in some other tab. That way no session gets destroyed, and the token is intact too :|

Comment: If he uses the token on your server it is destroyed. The hacker could just get another token by refreshing the page but it will prevent automated attacks.

Comment: Why destroy the token on every request? If you create a token that has the same properties as a session ID (secure random and proper length), then this token shares the same properties as the session id. The only way the attacker can get the token in this case would be either sniffing the network or through XSS, but if you have XSS, CSRF-protection fails anyways. And yes, use SSL.

From an AJAX application, having the token destroyed every time it is used, can become a pain, as you would have to keep track of what the current valid token is, when doing multiple concurrent asynch. requests.

Comment: Btw. you could put the token in the header instead of as a POST parameter if you are using jQuery:
http://erlend.oftedal.no/blog/?blogid=118

Comment: I feel safer with single access token. Because we use them for external api calls that we don't trust much. But I agree that it is painful to manage.

Answer (score 0):

I would define a *stolen token* as a token that is used by someone else, and not the one you have send the token to. If you send someone a token he can't really *steal* it from himself.

If you are concerned that a user can run a malicious script with his own token, your design seems to be broken. You can't prevent a user from sending data that you didn't indented to receive. It's your job to validate any data, the session token is just there to identify multiple requests by the same client.

It could be a security issue if you send that token over unsecured http. Then it could easily be stolen by monitoring the clients network.