# CSRF Tokens.Are they really secure?

Tags: jquery, security, csrf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Doubt on prevention of CSRF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166354/doubt-on-prevention-of-csrf)

I have a few serious doubts :

We basically use random session tokens to check if a  POST request has originated from a desired page.  Suppose a malicious  user opens up the page,right clicks and views the source of the page.then he gets the token for the current session. He opens up another tab,and uses the token wit his own malicious script. This way,the session is intact, and the token has been stolen too! How can this be prevented ?

Like if an ajax function says :

```
$.post("abcd.php",{'uid':userid,'code':'<?php echo  md5($_SESSION['randcd']); ?>'}
```

Clearly, the token will be visible, to the hacker in the source code. And since the session isn't destroyed , the token will not change. Hence my doubts

I thank everyone here for being so  patient on this wonderful forum.

Thanks for all the help